# How to position the 3 divs in one column when the browser's width is resized?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a 3 column layout in my HTML which looks like this

```
[ [leftdiv]     [centerdiv]      [rightdiv] ]
```

I'm not really a UI guy so I need help to deal with this stuff in css
for responsive design. The HTML layout below represents the above sketch.

```
   <div class="container">

        <div class="leftdiv" style="width:25%;height:auto;float:left; background-color:white">            

        </div>

        <div class="centerdiv" style="width:50%;height:auto;float:left; background-color:white">

        </div>

        <div class="rightdiv" style="width:25%;height:auto;float:right;background-color:white;margin-top:15px">

        </div>

    </div>
```

I need to make my 3 column divs to be responsive based on the screen width of the browser. So let's say if I resize
my browser's width to a lesser width like a screen width of a smart phones or tablet, the 3 divs should realign themselves
relatively like this below

```
[

 [leftdiv]   

 [centerdiv]  

 [rightdiv] 

]
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Is bootstrap an option? You can use bootstrap to make your life easier.

Comment: @almostabeginner I used bootstrap on this but if I resize my browser it will just compressed the width of the 3 divs in a smaller width but instead of compressing the width of the 3 divs I just want it to position themselves relatively in one column. What have I missed here?

Comment: @timmack to do it in bootstrap, give the columns bootstrap grid classes. I'll update my answer with an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a `@media` query

```css
.col {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  background: white;
}

.centerdiv {
  width: 50%;
}

.rightdiv {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .col {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftdiv col">left
  </div>
  <div class="centerdiv col">center
  </div>
  <div class="rightdiv col">right
  </div>
</div>
```

To do this in bootstrap, just utilize the grid column classes.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">left</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">center</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Mike, Thanks, I got it now. I just had no clue how easy it is to implement in bootstrap before you teach me that way. Newsbies in the club. Thanks again buddy.

Answer (score 2):

They're called `@media` queries and they are the underlying principle of responsive design. They are basically wrappers around `CSS` delarations applying only if the `@media` query condition is true.

```css
.leftdiv, rightdiv, centerdiv {
  background-color: white;
}
.right-div {
  margin-top:15px
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .leftdiv {
    width:25%;
    float:left; 
  }
  .centerdiv {
    width:50%;
    float:left; 
  }
  .rightdiv {
    width:25%;
    float:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftdiv">Left div</div>
  <div class="centerdiv">Right div</div>
  <div class="rightdiv">Center div</div>
</div>
```

I've placed your inline `style`s in `CSS`, where they belong (you can't use media queries without either a `<style>` tag or a stylesheet - `.css` file); I also streamlined them a bit.
Since what you want is default `<div>` behavior, I only placed the rules making them behave like columns (`float`s and `width`s) in a media query that applies on devices wider than `600px` (CSS pixels).

Of course, you can change `600px` to whatever you like and you can have as many `@media` queries as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `display:flex` with media queries to adjust the layout.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xdr9fhh1/

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftdiv">left</div>
  <div class="centerdiv">center</div>
  <div class="rightdiv">right</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.leftdiv, .rightdiv{
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
.centerdiv{
  flex-grow: 2;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .container{
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```